# Search multiple categories and Industries from relational table using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have three table and I need to find industries based on my search keyword which is exists in category table.

For Reference-
 I have attached the [screenshot for table description](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-qOJIV_wJCf4/UjgjUuFd-OI/AAAAAAAAAXk/0tjY_n3t4Eg/w601-h404-no/table_relations.png)

i. category table id is exists in categories_to_industries 
ii. categories_to_industries id is exists in industries
ii. Every category have n number of industries.

I want to have a mysql query to fetch industry name by category name.

Hope this information is enough. Let me know if anything else want to know about the structure.

Please help me if anybody have good solution for this.

Comment: please, put the structure and sample data into the post, so people could see it instantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `INNER JOIN` is all you need.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Industries a
        INNER JOIN Category_to_industries b
            ON a.ID = b.industry_id
        INNER JOIN Categories c
            ON b.category_ID = c.id
WHERE   c.category_name = 'Fired'
```

The letters (`a`, `b`, `c`) you see in the sql query are called alias.

To further gain more knowledge about joins, visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    SELECT industry_id FROM category_to_industries WHERE category_id = 
       (

       SELECT id FROM categories WHERE category_name = "Fired"
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much straightforward:

```
SELECT Industries.* FROM Industries
JOIN category_to_industries ON (Industries.id = category_to_industries.industry_id)
JOIN Categories ON (Categories.id = category_to_industries.category_id)
WHERE Categories.category_name='Fired';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

`select industry_name from Industries where id in (
select industry_id from category_to_industries where category_id in(
(select id from Categories where category_name = "Fired")
));`